# How to return text before new line and ** charactrers in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Column tasumma of type TEXT contains lines.
Start of comment is marked with two ** characters in start of line. Starting from this all text to end of column should ignored.
How to return text before commend line. For example if column contains text

```
2*31
** This is multiline
comment starting with ** characters in start of line
```

must return   2*31

I tried expression

```
 CASE when tasusumma like '%**%' then 
     substring( tasusumma for position( '**' in tasusumma)-1) 
 else tasusumma end
```

but it looks a bit ugly.

Is there a better way in Postgres e.q. using regexp substring ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `CASE when tasusumma like '%**%' then`? (Extra %)

Comment: Yes. This was mistake. I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a modification to @Bohemian's answer, use regexp_replace:

```
regexp_replace(tasusumma, '\*\*.*', '', 'g')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/643

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex extraction:

```
substring(tasusumma from '.*(?=\*\*)')
```

Here's [this code running in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/644)

Comment: @Andrus I misunderstood the question, I have fixed the regex to return "abc". This answer is shorter and neater than the currently accepted one - you may consider at least upvoting this one :)

Comment: Your answer returns empty string if string does not contain ** and invalid result for string like `x**y**` . Accepted answer returns correct results in both cases. For second case correct result is `x` but your expression returns `x**y`

Comment: Plus of your answer is that it works probably in earlier PsotgreSql version than accepted one. There are older Postgresql servers in some sites.

Comment: I modified expression using wildplasser answer to `regexp_replace(tasusumma, E'\n\\*\\*.*', '', 'g')`  Hopefully this allows ** to be inside formulas and assumes that comment starts with ** as first two characters in line as is in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE fuzz
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY key
        , fuzz varchar
        );

INSERT INTO fuzz (id, fuzz) VALUES
(1, E'one ** TWO')
, (2, E'one ** COMMENT\n two.')
, (3, E'one ** COMMENT\n two.\*\* THREE')
        ;

SELECT f.id
        , regexp_replace ( f.fuzz, E'\\*\\*[^\n]*', '' , 'g' )
FROM fuzz f
        ;
```

Result:

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "fuzz_pkey" for table "fuzz"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
 id | regexp_replace 
----+----------------
  1 | one 
  2 | one           +
    |  two.
  3 | one           +
    |  two.
(3 rows)
```

FROM the [Fine Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)
Note: If you have standard_conforming_strings turned off, any backslashes you write in literal string constants will need to be doubled. See Section 4.1.2.1 for more information.

Note: contrary to the OP request, the above code assumes that '**' comments should end at the end of the same line; the next line is *not* considered part of the comment. This is the way that '--' comments are handled in sql, and '//' comments are handled in C or C++.

Comment: Thank you. Great code. However question states that from ** to `end of column` characters should ignored so I marked PinnyM answer as answer.

Comment: For comments that go to the end of line, it is normal to treat the next line not as a comment. But you might have different requrements.

Comment: Database text column contains formulas, possibly in multiple lines. After formula there may be comments which start at next line to end of column, possibly in multiple lines. Comment starts if first two characters in line are `**`. Remaining comment lines may start with any characters. My goal is to extract formulas without comments.